# How can I properly match subjects in my sample based on behavioral performance?

Tags: experimental-psychology, experiment-design, aging

I have brain and behavioral data for which I am comparing two groups- younger and older adults. I would like to select a subset from the younger and older group that are matched for behavioral performance, in addition to ensuring that other factors do not confound the behavioral performance, such as education and IQ. I was wondering how I can go about systematically creating these two age group subsets? I was reading a bit on propensity score matching and was wondering if this is the way to go?
Thank you!